# Getting toArray value out of sortable()

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something stupid here, as it seems like a very basic problem.

I am using sortable() on a short list and want to return an array of the ids for the sorted list. My code for this works and I can do a console.log from within the function to correctly display the sorted ids. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this array for global use.

Here's my code:

```
  $(function() {
    var sortedGrades = [];
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        //connectWith: '.sortable-list',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var sortedGrades = $(this).sortable('toArray');

            console.log(sortedGrades);

        },
        create: function( event, ui ) {
            var sortedGrades = $(this).sortable('toArray');

            console.log(sortedGrades);
        }

    });

    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });

});
```

If I declare the sortedGrades array globally by using `sortedGrades = [] ;`, the array is blank when I try to call it into another function later. If I don't declare it globally, it errors as undefined when I try to call it.

Any ideas what I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it, though I'd be interested if anyone can explain to me why doing it like this works.

I changed the code to:

```
    $('#sortable').sortable({

        update: function(event, ui) {
            sortedGrades = $(this).sortable('toArray');
            sortedGrades2 = sortedGrades ;
            console.log(sortedGrades);
        },
        create: function( event, ui ) {
            sortedGrades = $(this).sortable('toArray');
            sortedGrades2 = sortedGrades ;
            console.log(sortedGrades);
        }

    });

    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();


  });

});
```

(i.e. I added the `sortedGrades2 = sortedGrades;` lines)

I then called `sortedGrades2` into my other function instead. I don't get why I had to do this, but it works. As it stands, I don't think either array is actually declared anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the `var` keyword you are re-declaring each time a new `sortedGrades` variable, that is visible only inside the function in which you are declaring it.

Try with:

```
$(function() {

    var sortedGrades = [];

    $('#sortable').sortable({
        //connectWith: '.sortable-list',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            sortedGrades = $(this).sortable('toArray');
            console.log(sortedGrades);
        },
        create: function( event, ui ) {
            sortedGrades = $(this).sortable('toArray');
            console.log(sortedGrades);
       }
    });

   $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

});
```

Comment: Thanks. If I do that, the sortedGrades continues to be undefined when I call it in a function `gradeSort(type, sortedGrades) ;` 

Alternatively, if I place the `var sortedGrades = [];` on document.ready, the array is sent through to the gradeSort function as empty.